# REMOVEFILTER/ALL DAX not working as expected : Power BI : Direct Query

Tags: view, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure, directquery

There is a scenario were we are using REMOVEFILTER DAX function to remove the effect of few columns on the calculation(measure). What we could observe is, the function is working fine till it has maximum 2 columns included within. If we try to add more columns (3 or more) in REMOVEFILTER, the function does not work as expected.

Note : The dataset is a single table (actually a view which has multiple join conditions). We are using a Direct Query mode.
Current Architecture Limitation : Can not use star schema as a model.

Used **ALL** also, but still the same effect.
Any help here shall help us greatly.

Best Regards,
Pratik

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are facing is probably related to Auto Exists. Please read the blog and watch the video shared below:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-dax-auto-exist/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRntX-HiiN8